# How to set one view in vertical linearlayout in top and another in bottom programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to create programmatically parent LinearLayout 
and 3 TextViews.
One TextView must be aligned in top left, the second one in the center of parent
and the third one to the right and bottom of my screen. Everything must be done in code.
I'm almost done, but there is still some problem.
All my 3 views are on the top 
[image]

My code:

```
public class ActivityFour extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;

    private static final int TV_ID1 = 101;
    private static final int TV_ID2 = 102;
    private static final int TV_ID3 = 103;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        mLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams llParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        setContentView(mLinearLayout, llParams);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linlayout_params1 =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linlayout_params2 =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linlayout_params3 =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                              LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        linlayout_params1.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
        tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setId(TV_ID1);
        linlayout_params1.gravity = Gravity.START;
        linlayout_params1.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        mLinearLayout.addView(tv1, linlayout_params1);
        tv1.setText("TextView number ONE");

        linlayout_params2.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
        tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setId(TV_ID2);
        linlayout_params2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        mLinearLayout.addView(tv2, linlayout_params2);
        tv2.setText("TextView number TWO");

        linlayout_params3.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
        tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setId(TV_ID3);
        linlayout_params3.gravity = Gravity.END;
        mLinearLayout.addView(tv3, linlayout_params3);
        tv3.setText("TextView number THREE");
    }
}
```

After adding the weight property to all view.params it looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the `LinearLayout` fill all the available space, you need to set the `android:layout_weight` attribute on the middle child `View`. You can do it programmatically by using a [Constructor which takes the weight as third parameter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int,%20int,%20float)):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linlayout_params2 =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
```

Comment: after adding the weight to all view.params it looks like i wished but not there is some space in bottom. Please can you take a look the last added picture in subscription.

Comment: Did you still set the `android:layout_gravity` for the child `View`s like you did before?

Comment: I've just added a weight as you said as a third patameter for each layoutparams of textview

Comment: @Mister Smith - Well, I said to just set the attribute to the middle child `View`. And it needs a `android:layout_gravity = "center"` Right now it looks like you discarded all the layout_gravity stuff ("top|start" is the default)

Comment: You can set the same layout_weight to all three Views but then you have to keep all the layout_gravity settings which you had before. If you want to get a picture of what is the difference you can use [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174193/discussion-between-mister-smith-and-0x0nosugar).

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all no need to create liner layout for all textview you can do like this:

in xml file :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    tools:context=".activity.TestActivity"/>

and in activity file :

LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.test);

        TextView product_1 = new TextView(this);
        product_1.setText("Product 1");
        product_1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,1f));
        layout.addView(product_1);

        TextView product_2 = new TextView(this);
        product_2.setText("Product 2");
        product_2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,1f));
        product_2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(product_2);

        TextView product_3 = new TextView(this);
        product_3.setText("Product 3");
        product_3.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,1f));
        product_3.setGravity(Gravity.END|Gravity.BOTTOM);
        layout.addView(product_3);
```